# Can I copy this array any faster?

Tags: c#, optimization, bitmap, copy, arrays

Is this the *absolute fastest* I could *possibly* copy a `Bitmap` to a `Byte[]` in `C#`?

If there is a speedier way I am dying to know!

```
const int WIDTH = /* width */;
const int HEIGHT = /* height */;


Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
Byte[] bytes = new byte[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4];

BitmapToByteArray(bitmap, bytes);


private unsafe void BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap, Byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

    fixed(byte* pBytes = &bytes[0])
    {
        MoveMemory(pBytes, bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer(), WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4);
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
private static unsafe extern void MoveMemory(void* dest, void* src, int size);
```

Comment: Don't use `WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4` to calculate the size of the bitmap. Use `bitmapData.Stride * HEIGHT`. It works even when the rows have padding.

Comment: I know, its just an example. Thanks though :)

Comment: Do you know there is actually a Bitmap constructor that allows you to provide your own buffer for the bitmap? This could be a pinned managed array.

Comment: @jdv-Jan de Vaan -- Yes, but i was going the other way.  I had a bitmap and needed a byte array.

Answer (score 7):

Well, using [`Marshal.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) would be wiser here, that at least cuts out on the (one time) cost of looking up the DLL export.  But that's it, they both use the C runtime `memcpy()` function.  Speed is entirely throttled by the RAM bus bandwidth, only buying a more expensive machine can speed it up.

Beware that profiling is tricky, accessing the bitmap data the first time causes page faults to get the pixel data into memory.  How long that takes is critically dependent on what your hard disk is doing and the state of the file system cache.

Comment: The P/Invoke `RtlMoveMemory` version still performs a significant number of times better than `Marshal.Copy()` in my tests.  I agree profiling is tricky for something like this, but I wouldn't say there is compelling evidence to switch to using `Marshal.Copy()`.  Thanks for the answer anyhow, would +1 but for some reason it won't let me :\

Answer (score 4):

I'm reading into this that you're looking to do pixel manipulation of a bitmap.
So logically, you're wanting to access the pixels as an array in order to do this.

The problem your facing is fundamentally flawed, and the other guys didn't pick up on this - and maybe this is something they can take away too?

Basically, you've gotten so far to be messing with pointers from bitmaps, I'm going to give you one of my hard earned "secrets".

YOU DON'T NEED TO COPY THE BITMAP INTO AN ARRAY.  Just use it as it is.

Unsafe pointers are your friend in this case.  When you hit "bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer()" you missed the trick.

So long as you have a pointer to the first pixel, and the Stride, and you're aware of the number of bytes per pixel, then you're on to a winner.

I define a bitmap specifically with 32 bits per pixel (memory efficient for UInt32 access) and I get a pointer to first pixel.  I then treat the pointer as an array, and can both read and write pixel data as UInt32 values.

Code speaks louder than words.  have a look.

I salute you for making it this far!

This is untested code, but much is copied from my source.

```
public delegate void BitmapWork(UInt32* ptr, int stride);

    /// <summary>
    /// you don't want to forget to unlock a bitmap do you?  I've made that mistake too many times...
    /// </summary>
    unsafe private void UnlockBitmapAndDoWork(Bitmap bmp, BitmapWork work)
    {
        var s = new Rectangle (0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height); 
        var locker = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 320, 200), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        var ptr = (UInt32*)locker.Scan0.ToPointer();

        // so many times I've forgotten the stride is expressed in bytes, but I'm accessing with UInt32's.  So, divide by 4.
        var stride = locker.Stride / 4;

        work(ptr, stride);
        bmp.UnlockBits(locker);
    }

    //using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    unsafe private void randomPixels()
    {
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        // 32 bits per pixel.  You might need to concern youself with the Alpha part depending on your use of the bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 200, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        UnlockBitmapAndDoWork(bmp, (ptr, stride) => 
        {
            var calcLength = 300 * 200; // so we only have one loop, not two.  It's quicker!
            for (int i = 0; i < calcLength; i++)
            {
                // You can use the pointer like an array.  But there's no bounds checking.
                ptr[i] = (UInt32)r.Next();
            }
        });            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at `System.Buffer.BlockCopy`. 
This function is also very fast and it might be competetive in this setup as you are copying from managed to managed in your case. Unfortunately I can not provide some performance tests.

Comment: `Buffer.BlockCopy(Array, int, Array, int, int)` won't quite work here even though I am copying managed to managed.  All I have for the `Bitmap` data is an `IntPtr` to the start of the internal data.  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score -3):

I think this is faster (I actually used it):

```
// Bitmap bytes have to be created via a direct memory copy of the bitmap
private byte[] BmpToBytes_MemStream (Bitmap bmp)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    // Save to memory using the Jpeg format
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // read to end
    byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
    bmp.Dispose();
    ms.Close();

    return bmpBytes;
}
```

[Original Source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=358917)

Comment: Seriously, what will you do with a byte array with a JPEG? Decode the JPEG again to obtain the actual pixels? Oh, and did you know that JPEG is a lossy format?

Comment: Your function: `0.00064 ms` > Original: `0.0000251 ms` -- Meaning this one is about 25x slower

Comment: This is the safest option, but also the slowest.